# Java Spring контроллер открывает статический js файл

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

у меня есть Spring Boot проект.
Security настроен так, что есть неавторизованный доступ к "/js" и к "/". GetMapping("/") настроен на "redirect:/projects".
И всё работает, до того момента пока я не добавляю в общий для всех страниц шаблон js скрипт bs-custom-file-input.js. После добавления скрипта в common.ftl, вместо таблицы с проектами "/projects" пользователю отображается код скрипта .

**common.ftl**

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bs-custom-file-input.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Js скрипт лежит /resources/js/bs-custom-file-input.js:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

WebSecurityConfig выглядит следующим образом:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/js").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .expiredUrl("/");
    }
```

В MvcConfig добавлены ресурсы:

```
registry
            .addResourceHandler("/js/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/js/");
```

Mapping следующий:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String hello()
{
    return "redirect:/projects";
}

@GetMapping("/projects")
    public String projectsShow(Map<String, Object> model,
                               @AuthenticationPrincipal User user)
    {
        Map<String, Long> projectsWithMistakes = new HashMap<>();

        List<Project> projects_read = new ArrayList<>();
        projects_read.addAll(userRepo.findUserById(user.getId()).getProjects_read());
        projects_read.sort(Comparator.comparing(Project::getProjectname));

        projectService.getMistakesCount(projectsWithMistakes, projects_read);

        Set<Project> projects_write = userRepo.findUserById(user.getId()).getProjects_write();

        model.put("projetswrite", projects_write);
        model.put("projectsmistakes", projectsWithMistakes);
        model.put("username", user.getUsername());
        model.put("isProjects", true);
        model.put("projects_read", projects_read);
        return "projectList";
    }
```

Пользователь после авторизации видит вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть подозрение, что security не пропускает переход на /projects. Попробуйте добавить адрес в resourceHandler

Comment: У Вас на странице html ссылка на скрипт, вот его и выдает